# Installing icon library for react version 15.6.0

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, icons, package.json, compatibility

I have an old project that uses react version 15.6.0, and I want to install a new library to use icons.

I tried FontAwesomeIcons library but it seems to not be compatible with this react version.

Here is the package.jason of the project:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "airbnb-js-shims": "^1.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-plugin-macros": "^3.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "dns": "file:./src/dns",
    "glamor": "^2.20.40",
    "js-cookie": "2.1.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
    "react": "^15.6.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.0",
    "react-bootstrap-autosuggest": "^0.5.0",
    "react-bootstrap-switch": "^15.5.0-a",
    "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^2.0.0-alpha.3",
    "react-click-outside": "^2.3.1",
    "react-datetime": "^2.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.0",
    "react-loading-spinner": "^1.0.12",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-redux-multilingual": "^1.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.13",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.10",
    "react-sortable": "^1.2.0",
    "react-sortable-component": "^1.0.0",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^0.6.8",
    "react-toastify": "^4.1.0",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "smoothscroll-polyfill": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.6.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-imports": "^1.4.1",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^4.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.0.1",
    "react-app-rewired": "^1.3.5",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build && mv build ./webagent && mkdir ./build && mv ./webagent ./build/webagent",
    "build:pre_prod": "react-app-rewired build",
    "build:prod": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Tried installing older versions and other libraries but woudn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React version 15.6.0 is quite old and was released on June 8, 2017. Most current icon libraries are built with newer versions of React in mind and may not be compatible with such an old version of React.

However, there are still some icon libraries that may be compatible with React 15.6.0. One such library is the "react-icons" library. According to their documentation, it supports React 0.14.x and above, which should include React 15.6.0.

You can install the "react-icons" library using npm or yarn, and then use it in your React application like this:

import { FaStar } from 'react-icons/fa';

```
function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <FaStar />
      <p>Star icon</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note that since React 15.6.0 is a very old version, you may run into compatibility issues with other libraries and components, so it may be worth considering upgrading to a newer version of React if possible.